# Xcode Debugger: fatal error: Array index out of range.. why?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, cell

I'm getting a `fatal error: Array index out of range` error when i run my application, but I don't see why. Here is my code:

```
  var rippleLocations: [MKRippleLocation] = [.TapLocation, .TapLocation, .Center, .Left, .Right, .TapLocation, .TapLocation, .TapLocation]
    var circleColors = [UIColor.clearColor(), UIColor.clearColor(),UIColor.clearColor(),UIColor.clearColor()]

 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return aSport.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MKTableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = aSport[indexPath.row].name
        cell.textLabel?.text = aSport[indexPath.row].name
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 16)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.rippleLocation = rippleLocations[indexPath.row]
        let index = indexPath.row % circleColors.count
        cell.rippleLayerColor = circleColors[index]

        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let cell = sender as! MKTableViewCell
        let row = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row
        let detail = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController
        detail.selectedSchool = aSport[row!]
    }
```

The error is highlighted on the `cell.rippleLocation = rippleLocations[indexPath.row]` string.. why is this error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of rows is equal to `aSport.count`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return aSport.count
}
```

Shouldn't that be

```
    return rippleLocations.count
```

? Or are you sure that `aSport` and `rippleLocations` always have the same number of elements? If you want to cycle through the ripple locations, replace

```
cell.rippleLocation = rippleLocations[indexPath.row]
```

with

```
cell.rippleLocation = rippleLocations[indexPath.row % rippleLocations.count]
```

Comment: oh ok, no they do not, I have more of the aSport array then the ripple locations, so should i even them out?

Comment: Yes, or you might want to cycle through them, just like with the colors. See my updated answer.

Comment: great! thats better actually

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the size of the rippleLocations arrays is less than aSport ...

So for example at the 10th row it will crash if aSport has 10 objects and rippleLocations has 8 objects only.

becuase in numberofRows method you're returning aSport's count